# Can a confluence subtree be more permissive than the root?

Tags: confluence

A group X in my company has a confluence space S. They have a small project P with an external group Y.

Since the project is small, I'd like not to make a separate space for P but rather a page subtree T in S. However:

- Y must see only T and not the whole space S
- X must see the whole space S including T

Can I do that? (I know I can't but maybe you're smarter than me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit complicated (depending on your Confluence admin experience), but [this](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Page+Restrictions#PageRestrictions-HowtoOpenPartofaSpace) should to the trick.

> Often there are cases for which a
>   section of a space should be opened to
>   a group or set of users (for this
>   example, we'll call them group B), but
>   the rest of the space should not be
>   visible to your main users (for this
>   example, we'll call them group A). In
>   this case:
>
> 1. Add 'view' permission for both groups A and B in space permissions.
> 2. Move the page to be opened to the root of the space. When browsing the
>      pages in the space, your normal space
>      home page and this page should both be
>      at the root level.
> 3. Add a page restriction to allow Group A and B to see this page.
> 4. Add a page restriction to your main landing page for Group A, thereby
>      excluding this set of pages from Group
>      B.
>
> You can repeat this with any page
>   hierarchy.

Comment: Good idea! So we put the subtree T to the very root of S, as a sibling of S/Home. Tried it, works. The only problem is that entering the space goes to S/Home, so the external group Y gets "No permission" which is not a very warm welcome. Can I trick Confluence into using a different home page (S/T) for the group Y?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely possible using normal permissions and setting the sub-folder explicitly, but you should include details like what operating system or file sharing software you are using.  Unix file permissions, Windows server shares, and work team file sharing websites all function completely differently in terms of permissions.

Also for future reference, example names for folders and groups are probably easier to understand than single letters, which are likely to remind people of math class =P

Comment: He did name the software: Confluence.

Comment: Oh.  He didn't capitalize it so I assumed it was a formal name for a folder from network theory or something similar.